# SELinux: Context u:object_r:usb-update_exec:s0 is not valid (left unmapped)

Tags: android, selinux

I am working on i.MX 6Quad SABRE-SD with Android 9. I am planning to add USB Re-flash (custom script) service in Android 9.

I got the following error on boot:

```
SELinux:  Context u:object_r:usb-update_exec:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
```

## init.rc

```
service usb-update /system/bin/usb-update.sh
        class main
        user root
        group root system
        oneshot
        seclabel u:r: usb-update:s0
```

## usp-update.te

```
type usb-update, domain;
type usb-update_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(usb-update)

domain_auto_trans(init, shell_exec, usb-update)
```

## file_context

```
/system/bin/usb-update     u:object_r: usb-update_exec:s0
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple problems with your policies:

1. Your `file_context` has to be named `file_contexts` instead (it's missing an 's').
2. Your `file_context` defines a context for `/system/bin/usb-update` and not `/system/bin/usb-update.sh`.
3. There should not be a whitespace in `u:object_r: usb-update_exec:s0` nor `u:r: usb-update:s0`.
4. You probably don't need the `seclabel` property in your `init.rc`.

Comment: I changed to "/system/bin/usb-update.sh     u:object_r:usb-update_exec:s0" . But, eventhough I got same error. Thank you

Comment: Have you added the directory of your `file_contexts` file to the `BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS`? See https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement#boardconfig

Comment: Yes this file_contexts directory is already added in BoardConfig.mk file.

Comment: Please check your `file_contexts` file with `checkfc $OUT/root/sepolicy path/to/your/file_contexts && echo $?`. It should return `0`.

Comment: Hi, I got error  "init: Service 'usb-update' (pid 1702) exited with status 1". After this service crashed and Android boot also stopped.